# Not Found: /votacao/votacao/templates/votacao/myScripts.js

Tags: javascript, html

So basically i have a server and a web site, and when i try to call my javascript function **validarComentário** i get the error  "Not Found: /votacao/votacao/templates/votacao/myScripts.js "

I dont know what im doing wrong, basically i have a index.html where im calling the myScript.js and also de jquery.js.
[js script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmvDR.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImgQ8.png)

I try to find the right path but the one that im using now seems right

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.